# Time interval between several dates (days and hours)

Tags: r, datetime

I know a lot of questions have been asked on the same subject but I have not found an answer to this particular question, despite trying to adapt other codes to my problem.

My data frame "v1" has more than 300 thousand lines with the variable "Date" in the following format:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2015-07-27 17:35:00 |
| 2015-07-27 17:40:00 |
| 2015-07-27 17:45:00 |

1st I want to know if all the "Date" intervals are in the 5 to 5 minutes interval. If not I would like to track where different intervals are.

2nd I pretend to create a new column where it can be seen the time stamp of the different intervals. For example, "time_int" where it would be seen "00:05:00", "00:05:00"...

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rollapplyr` to find the time difference between two consecutive rows. And then you can use `which` to find the rows that the time difference is not 5 minutes.

```
dt=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
dt=mutate(dt, Date=ymd_hms(Date)) %>%
  mutate(dt, Dif=rollapplyr(Date, 2, function(x) {
  return(difftime(x[2], x[1]))
}, fill=NA))
dt
                 Date Dif
1 2015-07-27 17:35:00  NA
2 2015-07-27 17:40:00   5
3 2015-07-27 17:45:00   5
4 2015-07-27 17:49:00   4

dt[which(dt$Dif != as.difftime(5, units="mins")),]
                 Date Dif
4 2015-07-27 17:49:00   4
```

Lastly, to format the times in your desired format:

```
dt %>% mutate(DifString=format(.POSIXct(Dif*60, tz="GMT"), "%H:%M:%S"))
                 Date Dif DifString
1 2015-07-27 17:35:00  NA      <NA>
2 2015-07-27 17:40:00   5  00:05:00
3 2015-07-27 17:45:00   5  00:05:00
4 2015-07-27 17:49:00   4  00:04:00
```

**Data**

```
text="Date
'2015-07-27 17:35:00'
'2015-07-27 17:40:00'
'2015-07-27 17:45:00'
'2015-07-27 17:49:00'"
dt=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you, the code gives me exactly what I want. I'm just not sure about "dt[which(dt$Dif != as.difftime(5, units="mins")),]" because it gives me the headers of the dataframe, something like this "# A tibble: 0 x 3
# ... with 3 variables: N <dbl>, Date <dttm>, Dif <dbl>" instead only "Dif" column which was I was expected.

Comment: It probably means that the difference between the times is always 5 minutes. You can try `dt$Dif != as.difftime(5, units="mins")` and see if everything is FALSE meaning that the difference is always 5 minutes. You can also try 

`which(dt$Dif != as.difftime(5, units="mins"))` and 

`dt$Dif[which(dt$Dif != as.difftime(5, units="mins"))]` and they should be empty vectors.

Comment: thank you again. the last two codes are handier since the 1st one gives all the lines and it's a bit tricky to follow when you have 1000 entries. just one more thing, these last 2 codes ignore NA's, right? It is just to make sure, cause I have one NA in the first entry (day and time 0) and it gives me the empty vectors.

Comment: Yes it should be fine with the NA in the first entry because the logical != operator is working component-wise, and which(c(NA, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))=c(2,3) (it ignores the NA).

Comment: great! appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option to calculate the difference using `lag`. If you'd like, you could create another column showing hours with `units = "hours"`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


df <- data.frame(date = ymd_hms(c("2015-07-27 17:35:00", 
"2015-07-27 17:40:00", "2015-07-27 17:49:00", "2015-07-27 19:49:00")))

df %>% 
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date),
         diff_minutes = as.numeric(diff, units = "mins"),
         time_int = format(.POSIXct(diff_minutes*60, "UTC"), "%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  select(date, diff_minutes, time_int) %>% 
  # Filter the data for a range of minutes
  filter(diff_minutes >= 5 & diff_minutes < 10)

# OUTPUT:

#>                  date diff_minutes time_int
#> 1 2015-07-27 17:40:00            5 00:05:00
#> 2 2015-07-27 17:49:00            9 00:09:00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Original Data**

```r
date
<S3: POSIXct>
2015-07-27 17:35:00             
2015-07-27 17:40:00             
2015-07-27 17:49:00             
2015-07-27 19:49:00
```